# how to get all previous data according to timestamp in kibana using py script?(it overrides each time)

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pycharm, kibana

Below is code where I am connecting the python script remotely and fetch the output.

*the server which executes the query is stored in the elastic search index: e2

the server which fails to execute a query is stored in elastic search index: e1*

now whenever I run this script,
I get

'SERVERNAME': SERVERNAME,'timestamp': ####,'ONLINE': "ONLINE"

and only 1 hit which is the recent one....not all hits (servername) in kibana discovery tab

**below is the picture**

[image: image showing kibana discovery mode for index having multiple servername but showing only latest one(overriding every time and update)]

**Below is python code:**

```
ES_HOST = {"host":  "localhost", "port": ####}

es = Elasticsearch(hosts=[ES_HOST])

filepath=r'c:\remote server\ServerList.csv'
#with open (filepath, 'r') as servers:
with open(filepath, 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as servers:
   for line in servers:
       l = line.split()
       #print(l)
       SERVERNAME = line.rstrip()
       #print(SERVERNAME)

       cnxn = pyodbc.connect(Trusted_Connection='no',
       Driver='{SQL Server}',
       Server=SERVERNAME,
       PORT='####',
       Database='####',
       UID='####',
       PWD='####')
       cursor = cnxn.cursor()
       #print("hureeee")
       #print(SERVERNAME)
       s=cursor.execute("select servername AS gandhiji from ######")
       row = cursor.fetchone()
       if row == None:
            print("There are no results for this query", SERVERNAME)
            e1 = {
                'SERVERNAME': SERVERNAME,
                'timestamp': datetime.utcnow(),
                'OFFLINE': "OFFLINE"
            }
            res1=es.index(index='rep100', id=1, body=e1)
            res1=es.get(index="rep100", id=1)
            print(res1['_source'])

            es.indices.refresh(index="rep100")
            res1=es.search(index="rep100", body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})
       else:
           print(SERVERNAME)
           e2 = {
               'SERVERNAME': SERVERNAME,
               'timestamp': datetime.utcnow(),
               'ONLINE': "ONLINE"
           }
           res2=es.index(index='re100', id=1, body=e2)
           res2=es.get(index="re100", id=1)
           print(res2['_source'])

           es.indices.refresh(index="re100")
           res2=es.search(index="re100", body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer:

1) need to modify

```
res1=es.index(index='UR_INDEXNAME', id=1, body=e1)
```

to

```
res1=es.index(index='UR_INDEXNAME', body=e1)
```

if we specify `id=1` in es.index in for loop that will run again and replace the existing data for the previous id.

2)

Also, for finding error in connection, use try and except in Python:

**QUERY---->** "TO SELECT SERVERNAME FROM****"

A) **TRY BLOCK:::** will give SERVERNAME WITH VALID CONNECTION AND VALID QUERY OUTPUT(NOT NULL OUTPUT)

Additionally, if you want null values server name for successfully connected servers then, use this code:

```
if row == None:
            print("There are no results for this query", SERVERNAME)
            e1 = {
                'SERVERNAME': SERVERNAME,
                'timestamp': datetime.utcnow(),
                'status': "ONLINE SERVER WITH NULL VALUES"
            }
            res1=es.index(index='rep100', id=1, body=e1)

       else:
           print(SERVERNAME)
           e2 = {
               'SERVERNAME': SERVERNAME,
               'timestamp': datetime.utcnow(),
               'STATUS': "ONLINE"
           }
           res2=es.index(index='re100', id=1, body=e2)
```

B)  **EXCEPT** pyodbc.Error::: will give SERVERNAME FAILED TO CONNECT

Please refer these links for more information:

- https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/114
- https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Exceptions